# Binding event handler prop with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

What is the proper way to declare event handler from container to the presentation widget so that I can access other props in the event handler function?

```
class ApplicationWidget extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handle_onload.call(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.handle_click}>
                <Header />
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => {
        return {foo: state.foo};
    },
    dispatch => {
        return {
            handle_click() {
                console.log(this)
            },
            handle_onload() {
                jQuery.get({
                    accepts: 'application/json',
                    success: (data) => dispatch(the_action_creator(data)),
                    url: `/initialize`
                });
            }
        };
    }
)(ApplicationWidget);
```

Currently the `this.props.handle_click` event handler logs `undefined` whenever the click event happens. If I want access to `this.props.foo`, what is the right way of doing it? My current implementation is

```
<div onClick={this.props.handle_click.bind(this)}>
```

in the `render()` method and it works as intended however according to the [linter](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) this doesn't look like a good practice. The following code doesn't seem to work after the container (generated by the `connect` function) is updated (the binding is reseted to `undefined` for some reason)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.handle_click = this.props.handle_click.bind(this)
}
```

So what is the right way to do this? Or am I doing this whole thing wrong?

Comment: I know hence I am looking for the proper way of doing it (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop `handle_click` is just a function that is passed to the component by reference, so it doesn't “know” anything about the scope (*this*) of the component. You can change that using the *bind* method that is available to all functions, like this:

```
class ApplicationWidget extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handle_onload.call(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.handle_click.bind(this)}>
                <Header />
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

To optimize this and prevent your linter from complaining, you can bind it in the constructor like this:

```
class ApplicationWidget extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handle_click = props.handle_click.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handle_onload.call(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handle_click}>
                <Header />
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So you almost got it right, but I wouldn't modify the props in the constructor, just add another method to the class.

Comment: Does it work with your Redux setup? I've only tested with a simple component